# Windows 7 environment variable not removable

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cygwin, environment-variables

I installed MKS on Windows 7 and with it MKS Toolkit was silently installed. This also seems to set some global environment variables like "TERM" and "TERMCAP". As these variables won't work together with cygwin I uninstalled MKS Toolkit again. But unfortunately the variables are still present.

I now have the problem that I only see those variables on the command line. I can not find them anywhere else. They do not appear under the GUI nor in the registry. How is this possible and how can I remove them anyway?

The only way I get cygwin to work correctly is to explicitly set all the invalid variables to an empty value. But this feels quite wrong. So where can I find and remove them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps commands were appended to your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.bashrc` files by the **MKS** installer?  If you can't find them in the Registry, then they are being set using traditional UNIX mechanisms (e.g., shell startup scripts).  You should also check `/etc/profile` and the files under `/etc/profile.d`.

Answer (score 1):

check the registry:

For System Variables:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

For User Variables:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`